# Photoshop CC2015: *Pasted* Vector Smart Objects not Launching Ai

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I get it that if I *place* an Ai file in my PSD, it will launch Ai for Smart Object editing. However, it used to be just last year that simply pasting a vector object from Ai into PSD file, it would be treated as an Ai file and launch Ai for editing.

Not happening anymore :( Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when you are pasting the vector object with in PS, that you have "Add to my current library" checked OFF.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Time to sign up here and pay it forward. Thanks a million, ErickP!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey @NisiRivera, if this answer did indeed help you, could you please accept it? This way the poster gets rewarded and our system can mark your issue as _resolved_ so it won't pop up in the future.